# What is the difference between the properties Keys and AllKeys on a NameValueCollection?

Tags: .net, collections

System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase has two similar properties:

```
  string[] AllKeys
  NameObjectCollectionBase.KeyCollection Keys
```

Do they provide different sets of data?  When would I want to use one over the other?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`AllKeys` is an `O(n)` operation, while `Keys` is `O(1)`. This is because `AllKeys` copies the keys into a new array, while `Keys` just returns a reference to `NameValueCollection`'s private key collection.  So beyond the difference in performance, the collection returned by `Keys` will change with the base collection as it's just a reference to the original, while `AllKeys` will be insulated from the changes because it's a copy.

This little test program shows the difference in behavior:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var collection = new NameValueCollection();

        var keys = collection.Keys;
        var allKeys = collection.AllKeys;

        collection.Add("Name", "Value");

        Console.WriteLine("Keys: " + keys.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("AllKeys: " + allKeys.Length);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Keys: 1
AllKeys: 0
```

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too.  You'd sure think a big difference like that would be explicit in the documentation.  (Or maybe named a little better to reflect the semantics).  Usually, the MSDN documentation is pretty excellent about things like that.  That's why this one threw me off-guard.

Comment: Agreed, bad name and unclear semantics.  Not to mention FxCop dislikes properties returning arrays for this very reason! Since this class is a leftover from the pre-generics days, perhaps Dictionary<string, string> or Dictionary<string, YourType> would be better now?

Comment: I see this lack of documentation all of the time in MSDN.

Comment: That whole class is goofy.  If you call ToString on it, it uses the wrong URL encoding and outputs values with %uXXXX encoding, which isn't valid in a URL querystring (must UTF8 bytes encoded as %XX).  There's a global app setting you can stick in app.config or web.config to stop the %uXXXX encoding: "aspnet:DontUsePercentUUrlEncoding".

Comment: Instead, you need to copy the values to a dictionary (the values are unencoded when accessed), then construct a new FormUrlEncodedContent instance from the dictionary like: `new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValueDict)`.  Then call `ReadAsStringAsync().Result` on the object to get a valid query string that can be assigned to the Query property of a UriBuilder.

Comment: The worst part is you know the developer was like "oh shoot, 'Keys' is taken..."

Answer (score 6):

According to MSDN's documentation, when using AllKeys, it's O(n) to retrieve all the values, whereas when using Keys it's O(1).

[Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.nameobjectcollectionbase.keys.aspx)

> Retrieving the value of this property
>   is an O(1) operation

[AllKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.allkeys.aspx)

> This method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count.

So basically, it seems that Keys has better performance.

Answer (score 5):

there however is the added benefit that you would be able to do operations on your collection using a foreach or a LINQ statement on the return of AllKeys().  Since its a copy, you won't get errors modifying a list currently being enumerated.